Activity not launched using deep linking to display browser page - MAUI
I have a Xamarin Forms app that I'm converting to MAUI. For Android, I've brought across working Xamarin code that authenticates on Dropbox. It's placed in a MAUI service. But on MAUI, the authentication stalls. I greatly doubt the problem is related to Dropbox, as explained below.
The code below uses Dropbox.Api v6.37.0 NuGet (same as used with Xamarin) In Xamarin it launches a Dropbox authentication browser screen, but fails in MAUI/.NET8 - the activity fails to start.
References to Dropbox api may not need scrutiny as it simply produces a url, which appears to be correct.
[Activity(Label = "Dropbox", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = false, Exported = true,
ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation, ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Nosensor)]
[IntentFilter ( new [] { Intent.ActionView },
      Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryBrowsable, Intent.CategoryDefault },
      DataScheme = "au.com.technologyinsights.myapp" )]
public class RedirectHandler : Activity
{
    protected async override void OnCreate ( Bundle savedInstanceState )
    {
        base.OnCreate( savedInstanceState );                // *** Not reached on MAUI ***
        Intent intent = Intent;                             // The intent that started this activity
        
        if ( Intent.Action == Intent.ActionView )
        {
            var uri = intent.Data;
            ...
            ...
        }
}


internal partial class DropboxAuthService
{
    Intent intent;

    internal partial bool IsBrowserInstalled ()   // *** Returns true on MAUI ***
    // Returns true if a web browser is installed
    {
        string url = "https://google.com";      // Any url will do
        Android.Net.Uri webAddress = Android.Net.Uri.Parse ( url );
        Intent intentWeb = new Intent ( Intent.ActionView, webAddress );
        Context currentContext = Platform.AppContext;
        Android.Content.PM.PackageManager packageManager = currentContext.PackageManager;
        ComponentName componentName = intentWeb.ResolveActivity ( packageManager );
        return componentName != null;
    }

    internal partial void OpenBrowser ( string url )   
    // Opens default browser
    {
        intent = new Intent ( Intent.ActionView, Android.Net.Uri.Parse ( url ) );
        Context currentContext = Platform.AppContext;
        currentContext.StartActivity ( intent );  // *** This line is executed on MAUI, nothing happens after that and the activity is not triggered.
    }
}

// The following 5 lines use Dropbox api to generate a Dropbox uri - on MAUI the generated uri seems correct.
DropboxCertHelper.InitializeCertPinning ();
pkce = new PKCEOAuthFlow ();                // Generates code verifier and code challenge for PKCE
StatePKCE = Guid.NewGuid ().ToString ( "N" );
Uri authorizeUri = pkce.GetAuthorizeUri ( OAuthResponseType.Code, clientId: clientId, redirectUri:redirectUri,
                                 state: StatePKCE, tokenAccessType: TokenAccessType.Offline, scopeList: null, includeGrantedScopes: IncludeGrantedScopes.None );

// NOTE: authorizeUri should look like this:
// https://www.dropbox.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=xxxxx&redirect_uri=com.mydomain.myapp%3A%2Foauth2redirect&state=51cbbd2b7bce4d7990bc72fc95991375&token_access_type=offline&code_challenge_method=S256&code_challenge=yyyyy                   

// Open authorization url in browser
dropboxAuthService.OpenBrowser ( authorizeUri.AbsoluteUri ); // *** This line is reached and executed on MAUI ***

// NOTE: On MAUI, the URL generated above appears to be of the correct form. It is:
https://www.dropbox.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=XXXX&redirect_uri=au.com.technologyinsights.behayve%3A%2Foauth2redirect&state=612f9abbd8ed4beda2212d730583cef0&token_access_type=offline&code_challenge_method=S256&code_challenge=s9ylxHmnpIbJR46t1N7lxHZNT7yP5y9wyM4Lu9LbcIs

The activity's DataScheme matches the Package name in AndroidManifest. dropbox.com is correctly configured as evidenced by the fact that my Xamarin app works correctly. Upgrading to Dropbox.api V7.0.0 has no effect.
In summary, I attempt to launch an activity to display a url in the browser. The url appears to be of the correct form. However the activity never starts.
Suggestions on how to fix or to troubleshoot further would be very welcome.

This is in debug mode with physical device

DataScheme = "au.com.technologyinsights.myapp" looks strange but it does work in Xamarin.

Possibly I need to somehow use builder.ConfigureLifecycleEvents in MauiProgram.cs??
